# Como somar valores numéricos de um array?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3

gostaria de saber como eu posso obter a soma de valores numéricos dentro de uma matriz. Meu caso é o seguinte, estou construindo uma tela de vendas, atualmente eu tenho um array com os produtos que o usuário seleciona para vender, estou exibindo eles na tela normalmente. Porém eu preciso capturar cada valor (preço) de cada produto, e no final eu preciso somar todos os preços para chegar ao valor total da venda, mas não estou sabendo como fazer.

A minha estrutura atual é a seguinte :

```
//Capturo o objeto produto que foi selecionado, 1 ou mais produtos//
if(produto.selecionado == true && produto.selecionado >= 1){
  this.produtosMarcados.push(produto);
} 
   this.venda.produtos = this.produtosMarcados;
   console.log(this.venda.produtos);
}

//Capturo a descricao do item e os valores//
//Capturo a descricao dos produtos, funciona perfeitamente//
var i: any;
for (i=0; i < this.venda.produtos.length; i++){
  console.log("Os produtos são " +this.venda.produtos[i].descricao);
}

//Capturo o preço de cada item, funciona perfeitamente//
var v: any;
for (v=0; v < this.venda.produtos.length; v++){
  console.log("Os valores são " +this.venda.produtos[v].preco);
}
```

Após esse botão escolha eu preciso colocar na tela o valor total da venda, onde preciso somar cada posição do array.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `Reduce`.

```
console.log(this.venda.produtos.reduce((total, produto) => total + produto.preco));
```

Mais sobre `Reduce` aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Dessa forma até da certo, porém eu só consigo obter a saída do item na posição[1]. Então ele não realiza a soma, ele exibe apenas o valor do item [1]
Até li sobre o reduce, mas ainda não consegui implementá-lo corretamente.

Comment: Agradeço a todos pela ajuda. Essa parte está resolvida, agora só estou com um outro problema, mas fiz outra postagem. Agradecido

Answer (score 1):

Concordo com o Bruno Soares, onde o Reduce é a melhor solução para a soma. Mas pelo que percebi, na variável this.venda.produtos tens um array de objectos.

Deste modo podes realizar o map para tornar esse array de objetos num array de valores e então depois utilizar o reduce para somar esses valores.

Exemplo:

```
var produto = [{preco: 1}, {preco: 2}];

console.log(produto.map((prod) => prod.preco).reduce((total, preco) => total + preco));
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, muito obrigado é o que eu precisava. Agora lhe faço uma pergunta, no lugar do {preco: 1} eu preciso colocar o valor dinâmico, no caso o preço do item, por exemplo 10,00 ou 15,00. Como eu faço essa substituição ? 
Desculpem mas não tenho muita fluência em javascript

Comment: Não sei se percebi bem a tua pergunta, mas olhando para o teu código inicial toda a informação que precisas (produtos e preços) não está na variável this.venda.produtos? Se assim for, só tens de substituir a variável produto que coloquei  pela tua e tá lá.

Comment: Consegui Resolver Francisco, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Deu tudo certo